# Why is my window resized to smaller than its minimum size by a wxBoxSizer

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I create the main window of my application with

```
Main::Main() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Test", wxPoint(64, 64), wxSize(1024, 768))
```

In this window I place another window of type `View` whose constructor looks like this:

```
View::View(wxWindow* parent) : wxHVScrolledWindow(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
```

The view is added to main in main's constructor through `m_view = new View(this);`

This gives me an application which looks like this:

[image]

which is exactly what I expected. I need to add more controls to my main window so I want to start using a sizer to have them laid out in a resolution independent manner. However, if I just add this simple sizer around my view:

```
auto sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
m_view = new View(this);
sizer->Add(m_view, 1, wxEXPAND);
SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
```

I end up with this:

[image]

I had hoped my view would expand and fit the main window, but this is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

I'm on version 3.14 of wxWidgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `SetSizer` instead of `SetSizerAndFit`.  The [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a29938af9828fd35da666536cdfb6b73c) for `SetSizerAndFit` says this:

> This method calls SetSizer() and then wxSizer::SetSizeHints() which sets the initial window size to the size needed to accommodate all sizer elements and sets the minimal size to the same size

However a scrolled window won't typically have a minimum size since it's made to just show scrollbars if its current size falls below a given size. So the `SetSizerAndFit` call tries to make the window large enough to hold a window with no minimal size, and the result is a window that only has its title bar, menu, and status bar.

Alternately, if your main frame will only ever have 1 child of type View, you could skip the sizer altogether.  wxFrame objects with only 1 child and no sizer automatically resize that 1 child to fill the frame's client area.